# Is it possible to set up multiple server blocks on NGINX without multiple domains

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a subdomain `labs.mydomain.com` which I'd like to host several web apps that I develop on different folders: `labs.mydomain.com/app1`, `labs.mydomain.com/app2`, `labs.mydomain.com/app3`. I'd like it to be the same domain separated by folders instead of creating a new subdomain for each one, just like in the example above.

The problem is that I use some framework on each project so I'd have to map `/app1` to `/app1/public` and `/app2` to `app2/public`.

Does NGINX accepts `server_name` to be like `labs.mydomain.com/app1`?

Is it possible to do so? If not, what would be the best alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx doesn't support `labs.mydomain.com/app1` as `server_name`.
But you can use [location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) directive to configure rules for your directories. Example bellow:

```
location /app1 {
    alias /var/www/app1/public/;
}

location ~ ^/app1/(.+\.php)$ {
    alias /var/www/app1/public/$1;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8888;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: Good to know! Should I add anything else if I want PHP to work on it? I already have a `location ~ \.php$ { ... }` block

Comment: For php you should add an additional section. I updated example.